# How to download file with Selenium and Firefox in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to download a file with Selenium, Geckodriver and Firefox all controlled from Python. The file actually get downloaded but driver still processing something even after file gets downloaded.

Code I use to download a file:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloaddir)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.viewableInternally.enabledTypes", "")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', "application/zip")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip")
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('http://speedtest.tele2.net/10MB.zip')
driver.close() # this code never gets called
```

Does anyone know what's going on?
I know there is workaround when you click on element.
The problem is I work with composed url which cannot be clicked but needs to be accessed directly.

```
Versions (linux):
  Gecko 0.29.1 
  Firefox 89.0
  Python 3.9.5
```

---

#### Update

There is implicit timeout configured to 5min and after that it will fail.

So my question is:
Is there a way how to download a file directly implemented in selenium without raising any kind of error (in ideal case of course)?

Comment: did you tried with urllib or requests? I am asking that because with that tools you can inspect the answer... In general Selenium is not design for that stuffs

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that. I kinda thought that it's not a proper way. Thank's, I got something working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @cards it is more convenient to use `requests` or `urllib` for this kind of work. You can use `selenium` to paginate or click, and then use `requests` by inspecting the website HTML.

```py
import requests

# retrieve the web content
response = requests.get("http://speedtest.tele2.net/10MB.zip")

# save it as local file
with open("filename.zip", "wb") as file:
  file.write(response.content)
```

P.S. The zip file that gets downloaded by your provided URL is damaged.